# Find elements between two dates and group them after

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

Table `___Bookings`:

```
|--------|------------|--------------|------------|------------|
| BOO_Id | BOO_RoomId | BOO_ClientId | BOO_DateCI | BOO_DateCO |
|--------|------------|--------------|------------|------------|
| 1      | 9          | 45           | 2018-01-02 | 2018-01-03 |
| 2      | 4          | 46           | 2017-12-30 | 2018-01-07 |
| 3      | 3          | 2            | 2018-12-31 | 2018-01-01 |
| 4      | 9          | 98           | 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-10 |
|--------|------------|--------------|------------|------------|
```

I'm looking to display, per day, the bookings in departure, in arrival or in house.

The desired output should be something like this:

```
2017-12-30  =  Booking #2 in arrival.
2017-12-31  =  Booking #3 in arrival.
            =  Booking #1 in arrival.
            =  Booking #2 in house.
2018-01-01  =  Booking #3 in departure.
            =  Booking #2 in house.
2018-01-02  =  Booking #1 in arrival.
            =  Booking #2 in house.
2018-01-03  =  Booking #1 in departure.
            =  Booking #2 in house.
2018-01-04  =  Booking #2 in house.
2018-01-05  =  Booking #4 in arrival.
            =  Booking #2 in house.
2018-01-06  =  Booking #2 in house.
            =  Booking #4 in house.
2018-01-07  =  Booking #2 in departure.
            =  Booking #4 in house.
2018-01-08  =  Booking #4 in house.
2018-01-09  =  Booking #4 in house.
2018-01-10  =  Booking #4 in departure.
```

What I already tried:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
      WHEN BOO_DateCI = '2017-12-31' THEN 'In Arrival'
      WHEN BOO_DateCO = '2018-01-10' THEN 'In Departure'
      WHEN '2017-12-31' > BOO_DateCI AND '2018-01-10' < BOO_DateCO THEN 'In House'
    END
FROM ___Bookings
WHERE BOO_DateCI = '2017-12-31'
OR BOO_DateCO = '2018-01-10'
OR :today BETWEEN BOO_DateCI AND BOO_DateCO;
```

But I can't get the `in house` bookings and can't group the booking depending the status `arrival`, `departure` or `in-house`.

Comment: DamDam You query and data has completely different set of dates, can you update the query to correct dates?

Comment: Done. Thanks to pointing this out.

Comment: can you show what the result is now? no 'in house' _at all_ or just not all of them?

Comment: Just to clarify: You used tagged your question with [tag:php] but form your question it looks like you're interested in a MySQL-only solution, is that correct?

Comment: ähm...shouldn't the `<` and `>` be just the other way round? (and maybe have a `=` attached to it)

Comment: @mmgross, it's correct.

Comment: In that case I suggest you remove the php-tag (or for that matter just accept the pending edit by someone else)

Comment: @DamDam u mean :today means todays date? If Yes, then :today BETWEEN BOO_DateCI AND BOO_DateCO is not valid.

Comment: _or_ you want `WHEN '2017-12-31' > BOO_DateCI` OR `'2018-01-10' < BOO_DateCO` - anyway, there's a logical mistake in that clause.

Comment: @Kumar, because I think I should run the query for each date I want to know no ?

Comment: No, how can today's date can be between two days?

Comment: @Jeff, yes perhaps the syntax is not the right one.

Comment: @Kumar, if I need a report form the whole January month, then I think I should compare all the 31 days of this month.

Comment: The status is determined by the 'BOO_DateCI' and 'BOO_DateCO'. If today == BOO_DateCI => 'in arrival'. If today == BOO_DateCO => 'in departure'. If today > BOO_DateCI today < BOO_DateCO => 'in house'.

Comment: By the way, what is BOO_DateCI and BOO_DateCo?

Comment: @Kumar 'CheckIn', 'CheckOut'

Comment: Why the duplicate question?

Comment: And why are you now only interested in a MySQL solution? PHP seems like a useful tool here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The principle

Here is my solution. The general idea is to generate a list of dates you are interested in and then `JOIN` this list with your bookings on the condition that a specific date is during the visit of a specific guest.

I'm assuming consecutive dates here. If you want to query several non-consecutive ranges, you could either repeat the process for each consecutive part or you could still query the full range and later filter out the dates you're not interested in.

## Implementation

First, you need to set the range of dates for which you want to generate that list. For the sake of convenience, I store them in two variables.

```
SELECT MIN(BOO_DateCI)
FROM Bookings 
INTO @first_date;

SELECT MAX(BOO_DateCO)
FROM Bookings 
INTO @last_day;
```

This will give you the whole range between the first check-in and the last check-out (including both dates as well). Of course you can just as easily choose the dates by setting those variables to some specific date:

```
SET @first_day := '2018-01-02';
SET @last_day := '2018-01-06';
```

The next step is to set a new variable that will act as a counter in the generation of our list of dates:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(@last_day,@first_day) + 1 INTO @i;
```

And now everything is in place to do the actual query:

```
SELECT 
  Datelist.date, 
  Bookings.BOO_Id,
  CASE
    WHEN Bookings.BOO_DateCI = Datelist.date THEN 'In Arrival'
    WHEN Bookings.BOO_DateCO = Datelist.date THEN 'In Departure'
    WHEN Datelist.date > Bookings.BOO_DateCI AND Datelist.date < Bookings.BOO_DateCO THEN 'In House'
  END AS status
FROM 
  (SELECT DATE(@first_day + INTERVAL @i:=@i-1 DAY) AS date
    FROM (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) dummy1,
         (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) dummy2
    HAVING @i > 0) Datelist
INNER JOIN Bookings
ON Datelist.date BETWEEN Bookings.BOO_DateCI AND Bookings.BOO_DateCO
ORDER BY Datelist.date, BOO_Id;
```

If you want to see that beast in action, check this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/241e3e1/1)**

## Generating the list of dates

Now, there is one part of that query, that I feel needs a little more explanation and that is how `Datelist` is generated:

```
SELECT DATE(@first_day + INTERVAL @i:=@i-1 DAY) AS date
FROM AnyTable
HAVING @i > 0
```

This will generate a list of dates, starting with `@last_day` going down to `first_day` (since `@i` is being counted down, not up). `AnyTable` here is really just any table from your Database. The caveat here is that you can not omit the `FROM` clause, because it needs rows, so that on every row the `@i:=@i-1` is performed. But that means, that your list of dates will contain at most the same number of rows as `AnyTable`. So, if you only have short tables (as in your example), this will fail. To get around that, we can generate some rows ourselves:

```
(SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) dummy1,
(SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) dummy2
```

As a replacement for `AnyTable` this will generate two derived tables with 4 rows each and cross join them, generating a result of 16 rows as 2 tables with 4 rows each are cross joined to give you 4x4 = 16 rows. If you need more, you can use more `UNION`s, more cross joins or both, as an example:

```
(SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) dummy1,
(SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) dummy2,
(SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) dummy3
```

will give you 4x3x5 = 60 rows.

Just to be clear: This does not mean, that your final result can contain only 60 rows, it means that the list of dates you generate can contain at most 60 dates.

### A word about performance

As you can see in this **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/751a9b/1)**, the query to generate 16 rows is obviously faster than the query to generate 100000 rows. The difference in performance is not that big of a deal, I ran that test multiple times and got times between 2ms and 8ms for the 16 rows and between 16ms and 60ms for 100000 rows. However, if you need a large number of rows and your code is executed very often you may be better off, creating a dummy table that just contains 100000 distinct numbers and use that instead of generating your derived table each and every time you run your query (Side note: 100000 days is almost 274 years, so I'm fairly certain that in your particular case you don't need that much, but it is still worth noting, that there are other options if performance is an issue)

On the other hand, if you're absolutely sure that `Bookings` has (in a real world scenario) more rows than you need, you can just use `Bookings` instead of `AnyTable`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Is it possible to specify a range of date?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, I just update my answer with a more detailed explanation and included instrunctions on how to specify a range of dates manually.

Comment: Do you know why when I try to run the query for 30 days I have only the datas for the last 15 days? Too much datas? Here the exemple running with the problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/303144/1

Comment: Thanks for your help. We are very near.

Comment: Yes, I know why: You only have 16 rows in the dummy, so your list of dates can contain at most 16 dates. Here is your updated example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/303144/2 The only thing I did was add another cross join, to increase the amount of rows from 16 to 64.  I explained that in the second part of my answer (below the largest code block). I suggest you read that again very carefully so you understand exactly what happens and don't run into that problem in your production code, this is very important! If you have any more questions, please let me know.

Comment: Hello, I read it carefully several times but got one question, is there a way to predict the number of `(SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) dummy1` I need? I will have hotel with 5 rooms but another one with 50. Or is there another way?

Comment: Well, it's difficult to say. However the limiting factor is not the number of rooms, just the number of dates, so if you know for example that you're only ever gonna need a range of a year or less, it will be enough to have 365 or only slightly more rows. I guess I should improve that explanation in my answer a bit.

Comment: @DamDam Updated my answer. I hope that clears things up a bit more.

Comment: Hello, the final goal is to have this repoort works for one month max (31 days max).

Answer (score 0):

Hi DamDam You need to use Stored Procedure for this requirement because we definitely need to use a loop to find how many arrival, departure and in house status per day. check my code below.

Here i initially calculated MIN date of your `check in date column (BOO_DateCI)` as starting date for the loop. Loop will run until today's date.

Inside the if loop, i am doing a select statement 
1. first column is date from the loop
2. second column is concat of Booking # + Booking Id as u required.
3. third column is the status calculation

> If  BOO_DateCI == dateFromTheLoop => It means arrival on that day.
>
> If BOO_DateCO == dateFromTheLoop  => It means departure on that day.
>
> If BOO_DateCI < dateFromTheLoop  AND BOO_DateCO > dateFromTheLoop  =>
>   It means still in house at that time

Then ordering these results by date.

Once done, i am adding 1 day to the loop date to use in the next iteration.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findBookings(d1 DATE) 
begin 
  LABEL1: 
  LOOP 
    SET d1 = Select MIN(BOO_DateCI) from ___Bookings; 

    IF d1 <= Date(NOW()) THEN 

      SELECT d1 as date, 
             Concat('Booking #', boo_id), 
             CASE 
                    WHEN BOO_DateCI = d1 THEN 'In Arrival' 
                    WHEN BOO_DateCO = d1 THEN 'In Departure' 
                    WHEN BOO_DateCI < d1 AND    BOO_DateCO > d1 THEN 'In House' 
             end 
      FROM ___Bookings Order by date;

      d1 = DATE_ADD(d1, INTERVAL 1 DAY);

    ITERATE label1; 
    end IF; 
    LEAVE label1; 
  end LOOP label1; 
end;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I have this error from phpMyAdmin : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select MIN(BOO_DateCI) from ___Bookings' at line 5`.